# Since when and how did the word "virgin" have connotations of purity?

Tags: meaning, etymology

This is what my Merriam-Webster's 11th Collegiate Dictionary says on the noun:

> 1 a : an unmarried woman devoted to religion  b capitalized   : VIRGO
>
> 2 a : an absolutely chaste young woman  b : an unmarried girl or woman
>
> 3 capitalized   : VIRGIN MARY
>
> 4 a : a person who has not had sexual intercourse  b : a person who is inexperienced in a usually specified sphere of activity *a virgin in politics*
>
> 5 : a female animal that has never copulated

This is what my Merriam-Webster's 11th Collegiate Dictionary says on the adjective:

> 1 : free of impurity or stain  : UNSULLIED
>
> 2 : CHASTE
>
> 3 : characteristic of or befitting a virgin  : MODEST
>
> 4 : FRESH, UNSPOILED;  specifically : not altered by human activity  *a virgin forest*
>
> 5 : a (1) : being used or worked for the first time  (2) of a metal   : produced directly from ore by primary smelting  b : INITIAL, FIRST
>
> 6 : of a vegetable oil : obtained from the first light pressing and without heating
>
> 7 : containing no alcohol  *a virgin daiquiri*

I also looked up my Oxford English Dictionary. The definitions and examples of the word as an adjective and noun are abundant and quite similar to the ones from Merriam-Webster.

Although a virgin is pure, I am not sure exactly what a virgin is pure *of*. Is the underlying assumption that sexual intercourse is dirty or that sexual misconduct is dirty? Also, when applied to something like *a virgin forest*, as one of the examples suggests, why would human activity (perhaps walking in the forest) would make the forest fresh or unspoiled by mankind? What if the human being wants to protect the forest because he or she has a green thumb and a passion for nature? Or is that usage referring to the corruption of nature by mankind for self-serving interests (wood, coal, charcoal, luxuries) at the expense of the animals and plants that live there?

Comment: You can't imagine? Really?

Comment: Since long before there was any *concept* of **English**. Etymonline: **virgin** [from **Latin** virginem (nominative virgo) "maiden, unwedded girl or woman,"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=virgin)

Comment: Meaning "*young woman in a state of inviolate chastity"* is recorded from c. 1300. Also applied since early 14c. to a chaste man. (Etymonline)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That only says unmarried or unwedded. It does not mention *purity*.

Comment: @DoubleU Maybe best to think about it this way: a virgin forest is one *untouched* by man. Its borders have never been *penetrated*. It is in its *original state*. No one has ever *been inside* it.  See? Nothing about sin or filth or value judgements.

Comment: @DanBron "No one has ever been inside it." I don't know about this. The Virgin Mary is a virgin, but she has Jesus inside her womb. Apparently, she is still venerated as a pure virgin, despite that Jesus was in there. Or perhaps, Jesus is the innocent lamb of God, is pure himself, so that does not affect Mary's purity.

Comment: @DoubleU Errr ... that's not what I meant by "being inside" a woman (or forest).

Comment: @DanBron Still, as the story goes, the Virgin Mary conceived by means of the Holy Spirit. Wouldn't it be correct to say that she was "touched" by the Holy Spirit? But if she was touched by the Holy Spirit, then she wouldn't be a virgin. She might still be pure, because the Holy Spirit, assuming Trinitarianism, is God, and God is pure.

Comment: I don't think the Holy Spirit is considered to be corporeal. It doesn't have a physical body; it is incapable of "touching" in the sense you're suggesting. Mary's pregnancy was (for Christians) a miracle, not a process.

Comment: @DoubleU: she did not have "sexual intercourse" with either the Holy Spirit or with Jesus. That's the sense of a virgin Dan Bron was referring  to with "being inside," in case you really didn't understand what he meant. So Mary = virgin by definition 4 (the most common use of the word today).

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of someone inside the forest, and by that analogy, I imagined Jesus inside the Virgin Mary. A better analogy would be someone *walking* inside the forest, because the act of walking is tantamount to penetrating. Anyway, the mother of Jesus is a virgin. Why then ascribe purity to her as well? How did the connection between virginity and purity came about? Hence the question of this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Latin *virgo* just means a young female person that has had no sexual contact with a man.  Later views about virginity are views of the church that held the view that sexual activity is sinful except when performed for the sole purpose of procreation. A virgin is free of this sexual sin. This has nothing to do with etymology, it is indoctrination of the medieval church and condemning of human sexuality. As literature shows the official representatives of the church had quite a different opinion.

Comment: This answer sounds plausible, but too simplistic. However, can you provide references for your answer? Quotes would be wonderful.

Comment: I'm no specialist for theological literature from St Augustine to Thomas of Aquin.  Theological moral doctrine is no specialty of mine. But with such books you can fill libraries.

Comment: Well, I meant supporting the assumptions. (1) That *virgo* means young female without sexual contact with a man. (2) That the connection between virginity and purity is due to the medieval church alone (which seems unfair to the Byzantine empire east of Europe, which may suggest that the connection may happen before Christianity was even born or before western Christianity developed). (3) That *purity* means *without sin*. (4) That the medieval church "condemned" human sexuality.

Comment: @DoubleU I too would like references for points 1-3, but as for (4), read the first few paragraphs of Book II of Augustine's Confessions: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3296/3296-h/3296-h.htm

Augustine considered sex (and music, and entertainment in general) to be (to put it simplistically) a distraction from God. Augustine was not equivalent to the medieval church, but he certainly did influence it.